# subsetting pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have found an inconsistency (at least to me) in the following two approaches:

For a dataframe defined as:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,np.NaN],[8,2,0,4,5]])
```

I would like to access the element in the 1st row, 4th column (counting from 0). I either do this:

```
df[4][1]
Out[94]: 5.0
```

Or this:

```
df.iloc[1,4]
Out[95]: 5.
```

Am I correctly understanding that in the first approach I need to use the column first and then the rows, and vice versa when using iloc? I just want to make sure that I use both approaches correctly going forward.

EDIT: Some of the answers below have pointed out that the first approach is not as reliable, and I see now that this is why:

```
df.index = ['7','88']
df[4][1]
Out[101]: 5.0
```

I still get the correct result. But using int instead, will raise an exception if that corresponding number is not there anymore:

```
df.index = [7,88]
df[4][1]   
KeyError: 1
```

Also, changing the column names:

```
df.columns = ['4','5','6','1','5']
df['4'][1]
Out[108]: 8
```

Gives me a different result. So overall, I should stick to iloc or loc to avoid these issues.

Comment: Yes, but with the first case you can't always guarantee it'll work. However, with positional indexing, the indices are interpreted consistently. I'd stick to using `loc` or `iloc` or `at` or `iat` _almost_ always unless there's no possibility of ambiguity.

Comment: You mean, the first approach won't work if I change the names of my rows and columns right?

Comment: Yes, it will work only if you don't have any column names, or if your column names are [0,1,2,3,4]. Else, it will either fail or give you a wrong result.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: And you should also test `df.index = [0, 2]; df[4][1]`

Comment: Yeah, changed it above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should think of DataFrames as a collection of columns. Therefore when you do `df[4]` you get the 4th column of `df`, which is of type Pandas Series. Afer this when you do `df[4][1]` you get the 1st element of this Series, which corresponds to the 1st row and 4th column entry of the DataFrame, which is what `df.iloc[1,4]` does exactly.

Therefore, no inconsistency at all, but beware: This will work only if you don't have any column names, or if your column names are [0,1,2,3,4]. Else, it will either fail or give you a wrong result. Hence, for positional indexing you must stick with `iloc`, or `loc` for name indexing.

Comment: I see, makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you are not using them correctly. It's just coincidence you get the same result.

`df.loc[i, j]` means the element in df with the row named `i` and the column named `j`

Besides many other defferences, `df[j]` means the column named `j`, and `df[j][i]` menas the column named `j`, and the element (which is row here) named `i`.

`df.iloc[i, j]` means the element in the `i`-th row and the `j`-th column started from 0.

So, `df.loc` select data by `label` (string or int or any other format, int in this case), `df.iloc` select data by `position`. It's just coincidence that in your example, the `i`-th row named `i`.

For more details you should read the [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

**Update**:

Think of `df[4][1]` as a convenient way. There are some logic background that under most circumstances you'll get what you want.

In fact

```
df.index = ['7', '88']
df[4][1]
```

works because the dtype of index is str. And you give an int `1`, so it will fall back to position index. If you run:

```
df.index = [7, 88]
df[4][1]
```

Will raise an error. And

```
df.index = [1, 0]
df[4][1]
```

Sill won't be the element you expect. Because it's not the 1st row starts from 0. It will be the row with the name `1`

Comment: I see, so as long as my rows are ordered 0 to n, this will work, but if they are named differently (say I happen to start ordering at 1 instead of 0) than this won't be consistent. Overall, I should probably stick to using iloc.

Comment: Yes, to select data by position, I strongly suggest you use `df.iloc[i, j]`

Comment: Actually I noticed that the rows are not the problem, even if they are named differently this still selects the correct row. The columns are what can cause a problem. See my edit above.

Comment: Not exact. If dtype of index (row) is 'str', and you use df[4][1], may be you can get the result. Try `df.index = [0, 2]` without int 1 in row names, `df[4][1]` will raise except.

Comment: I see, yes, that makes sense. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain that. I was using str and that makes a difference of course. I will change my edit in the original post above. Highly appreciate it!!!